# Can't call firebase cloud function from firebase firestore get().then() response

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, cors

I am trying to call a firebase cloud function from inside a firebase firestore `get().then()` function and it doesn't work. I get the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://europe-west3-timedshop-a5a66.cloudfunctions.net/createStripeCheckout' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> POST https://europe-west3-timedshop-a5a66.cloudfunctions.net/createStripeCheckout net::ERR_FAILED 500
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: internal
> at new m (error.ts:66)
> at b (error.ts:175)
> at k. (service.ts:296)
> at tslib.es6.js:102
> at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:83)
> at r (tslib.es6.js:73)

I work in vanilla html and js.
It works when I move the cloud function call outside the firestore `get().then()`. I can do that but I don't know how to make it wait for the `items` variable to obtain its values from firestore. Any solution would work for me.

```
function checkout() {
    var items = [];
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            db.collection("users")
                .doc(user.uid)
                .get()
                .then((data) => {
                    data.data().cart.forEach((cartItemData) => {
                        const words = cartItemData.split("-");
                        var collec =
                            cartItemData.charAt(0) == "0" ? "women" : "men";
                        var productID = words[0];
                        var color = words[2];
                        var sizeSelect = document.getElementById(
                            cartItemData + "sizeSelect"
                        );
                        var quantitySelect = document.getElementById(
                            cartItemData + "quantitySelect"
                        );
                        size =
                            sizeSelect.options[sizeSelect.selectedIndex].value;
                        var quantity =
                            quantitySelect.options[quantitySelect.selectedIndex]
                                .value;
                        console.log(productID, size, quantity, color);

                        let obj = {
                            productID: productID,
                            size: size,
                            quantity: quantity,
                            color: color,
                        };
                        items.push(obj);
                    });
                    callFunction(items); // here the firestore cloud function is called
                });
        }
    });
}
function callFunction(items) {
    const createStripeCheckout = firebase
        .app()
        .functions("europe-west3")
        .httpsCallable("createStripeCheckout");
    const stripe = Stripe(
        "pk_test_51JjMu9BKwB7V1OnRcwrPosArKwGOJORreGvWAnLmXbei1rDQzgsX8UIXFZTbSfhH5dmakmwyoLvVhteLeywH3zM400QT4cae9Y"
    );
    console.log(items.length);
    createStripeCheckout({ items: items }).then((response) => {
        const sessionId = response.data.id;
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            sessionId: sessionId,
        });
    });
}
```

Cloud function code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createStripeCheckout =
  functions.region("europe-west3").https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const lineItems = [];
    console.log("dataItems: ", data.items);
    data.items.forEach(async (prodData) => {
      console.log("prodData: ", prodData);
      const productID = prodData.productID;
      const size = prodData.size;
      const color = prodData.color;
      const quanity = prodData.quanity;
      let collec;
      let name;
      let price;
      let type;
      let description;
      if (productID.charAt(0) == "0") {
        collec = "women";
      } else {
        collec = "men";
      }
      await admin.collection(collec).doc(productID).get().then((qdata)=>{
        name = qdata.data().name;
        price = qdata.data().price * 100;
        if (productID.charAt(0) == "0") {
          type = "Women's" + qdata.data().type;
        } else {
          type = "Men's" + qdata.data().type;
        }
        description = type + " - " + size + " - " + color;
      });

      const obj = {
        price_data: {
          currency: "eur",
          product_data: {
            name: name,
            description: description,
          },
          unit_amount: price,
        },
        adjustable_quantity: {
          enabled: true,
          maximum: 5,
          minimum: 1,
        },
        quanity: quanity,
      };
      console.log("obj", obj);
      lineItems.push(obj);
    });
    console.log("lineitems: ", lineItems);
    const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret_key);
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ["card", "sepa_debit"],
      shipping_rates: ["<<string hidden by me>>"],
      shipping_address_collection: {
        allowed_countries: ["RO"],
      },
      mode: "payment",
      success_url: "http://localhost:5500/success",
      cancel_url: "http://localhost:5500/cancel",
      line_items: lineItems,
    });
    return {
      id: session.id,
    };
  });
```

Comment: Did you check some of the top previous questions on this topic? https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bgoogle-cloud-functions%5d%20No%20%27Access-Control-Allow-Origin%27%20header%20is%20present%20on%20the%20requested%20resource.%20If%20an%20opaque%20response%20serves%20your%20needs%2c%20set%20the%20request%27s%20mode%20to%20%27no-cors%27%20to%20fetch%20the%20resource%20with%20CORS%20disabled.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question properly and for this comment. I checked the questions from that topic and the only solution I found to match my problem a bit is to create Cloud Functions Invoker and set to allUsers. It did not work tho..

Comment: I recommend showing what you did to your Cloud Function in your question (there's an edit link right under it), as the problem is much more likely to be on that side than in the code of how you invoke it.

Comment: Alright, I just did.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem! It was a typing mistake I made. Instead of `admin.firestore().collection().....` I wrote `admin.collection().....`. Now it works.